# Dynamic programming algorithm (Kadane)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Description of the algorithm:
Maximum Subarray Problem
Given a sequence of n real numbers A(1) … A(n), determine a contiguous subsequence A(i) … A(j) for which the sum of elements in the subsequence is maximized.

Algorithm:

```
int kadane(int a[], int n)
{
    int overall_sum=0;  //overall maximum subarray sum
    int new_sum=0;      //sum obtained by including the current element

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //new_sum is the maximum value out of current element or the sum of current element
        //and the previous sum
        new_sum=max(a[i], new_sum+a[i]);
        cout << new_sum << " : ";
        //if the calculated value of new_sum is greater than the overall sum,
        //it replaces the overall sum value
        overall_sum=max(overall_sum, new_sum);
        cout << overall_sum << endl;
    }

    return overall_sum;

}
```

I understand that we are trying to break down the problem into small sub-problems. The idea is to determine the largest partial sum of the n-1 sub-sequence to find the largest partial sum of the n sequence. The code looks clear to me in the sense that I can work it out on paper to find the solution, but the idea seems like magic. Can someone provide a better explanation of this algorithm? or a proof of why it works?

Comment: Can you 4xplain the desired output of the problem a bit more? Currently I don't see why you just don't return the entire sorted set A as A is a subsequence of itself, and clearly there is no subsequence of A that has a larger sum. (I understand that this might not be relevant to what you're asking, but it'll help me help you)

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% precise, what the algorithm actually calculates is: maximum sum of a **non-empty** subsequence, for **non-empty** arrays (and zero for empty arrays, which is somewhat inconsistent). It makes a difference for arrays where all numbers are negative - if we counted an empty sequence as valid, then the result should be 0. The algorithm produces the largest negative number rather than 0 for such cases.

Proof:

At the beginning of the loop `new_sum` is always the maximum sum of those sequences that end on (excluding) `a[i]` (so, up to `a[i-1]` for `i>0`, `0` for `i==0`). Proof by induction of loop executions.  This is obviously true for `i=0` (`new_sum == 0` which is the sum of an empty sequence), and becomes true for `i+1` after the assignment, because the maximum-sum non-empty sequence ending at `a[i]` (which is the last element before `a[i+1]`) needs to include `a[i]` and is therefore the maximum of `a[i]` itself and the sum of `a[i]` and the preceding sequence.

The `overall_sum` is just the maximum of all `new_sum` values for `a[i]`, and therefore represents the maximum global subsequence (for some `i` it has to end at `a[i]`, so maxing over all `a[i]` works).

Answer (score 0):

You've already included the explanation of why it works in the code comments:

```
new_sum is the maximum value out of current element
or the sum of current element and the previous sum
```

Rather than thinking of the algorithm as the best sum *up to* element `i`, think of it as the best sum *starting at* element `i`.

Notice that the algorithm does not admit `new_sum` to ever not include the current element in the traversal. If ever `A[i]` alone is greater than `A[i]` added to sum-up-to-`A[i-1]`, it makes no sense for `A[i]` to include the previous section and we start counting from scratch. This guarantees that the sum we count starting at `A[i]` reaches the greatest it can be. We may see it decrease but by then we already updated the overall greatest sum if need be.